# Re-size a YouTube videos Iframe seems not Working

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, height, width

I just copy the embed code from the youtube videos and I need to use the youtube vidoes for advertisements

code from youtube

```
<iframe width="350" height="260" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_K9VcuVmDFg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have edited and updated  the code and it looks like this

```
 <div class="video">             
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_K9VcuVmDFg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

I have written my CSS and seems it does not have any effect on  the Size of the YouTube on web page

CSS

```
.video{
    width:67px;
    height:80px;
}
```

As i increase the size the video stays normal.How to re-size the videos to look big in size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the size of the iframe INSIDE the div with class 'video' so:

```
.video iframe {
   width:67px;
  height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define class in  iframe tag  then that css will take effect

```
<iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_K9VcuVmDFg"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     <style>
     .video{
      width:67px;
      height:80px;
     </style>
```